# Does fist and poison work in torchlight 2?

Tags: torchlight-2

Claw having -50% armor reduction and poison having -33% armor reduction will result in remainding 12% total armor left on enemy.

Or is 50% max?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to bring an enemy's resistances to negative values, resulting in increased maximum damage.